# Inputted number not showing in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display the number entered by the user onto a bootstrap modal, but for some reason it's not showing. The modal appears but the value "APno" doesn't appear next to "Appointment Number", can anyone see any reason why?

My code is as follows:

**form**

```
<form method="POST">
     Appointment Number:<br>

  <input type="number" name="apno" id="apno">
  <br>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success success" value="Submit" id="Submitbtn" name ="Submitbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit">
</form>
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Add apppointment details
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please add the following details

                <!-- Submit details -->
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Appointment Number: </th>
                        <td id="APNo"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <br>
                    <label for "comments"> Comments: </label>
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <label for "prescriptions"> Prescriptions: </label>
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="prescriptions" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>

                    <br><br>

                </form> 

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {



    $('#Submitbtn').click(function () {
        /* when the button in the form is clicked, display the entered values in the modal */

      $('#APNo').text($('#apno').val());


    });

    $('#submit').click(function () {
        // when the submit button in modal is clicked, submit the form 


         });
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're placing your data within a td element, but your td is not contained within table tags. Wrap your table elements within table tags and it should work just fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Submitbtn').click(function() {
    /* when the button in the form is clicked, display the entered values in the modal */
    $('#APNo').text($('#apno').val());
  });

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    // when the submit button in modal is clicked, submit the form 


  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> Appointment Number:<br>

<input type="number" name="apno" id="apno">
<br>
<br><br>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success success" value="Submit" id="Submitbtn" name="Submitbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit">

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        Add apppointment details
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Please add the following details

        <!-- Submit details -->
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Appointment Number: </th>
              <td id="APNo"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <label for "comments"> Comments: </label>
          <br>
          <textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
          <br>
          <label for "prescriptions"> Prescriptions: </label>
          <br>
          <textarea name="prescriptions" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>

          <br><br>

        </form>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Submit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```